# Titanium not launching Google Maps app in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

According to what I have been able to Google Titanium should launch the Google Maps app if it is installed, rather than the broweser, when the following code is run:

```js
Ti.Platform.openURL("http://maps.google.com/?saddr=51.24977493286133,-2.846895456314087&daddr=51.511971,-0.144470");
```

Unfortunately for me and others testing my app it only launches the browser even though Google Maps App is installed.

Is there a way to force opening of the Google Maps app if it is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of url use [UrlScheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme),for example like

```
Ti.Platform.openURL("comgooglemaps://?center=37.788463,-122.392545");
```

Comment: it's not working for me, can you please help? I want to send the longitude and the latitude to google maps native app, how can I do this?

Comment: This is my code.  if (OS_ANDROID) {
       Ti.Platform.openURL("https://maps.google.com/?q="+meetingLatitdue+","+meetingLongitude);
   }
   else{
     // Ti.Platform.openURL("comgooglemaps://?center="+meetingLatitdue+","+meetingLongitude);
      Ti.Platform.openURL("comgooglemaps://?center=37.788463,-122.392545&zoom=12");
   }.   //// Its not opening in IOS